# Running balance of a ledger with aggregated balances

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Imagine I have a ledger where I write `id, event_id, quantity, datetime` and I want to get up to date balances of the quantity grouped by event_id. The goal is to get the aggregated quantity per event_id quickly.

| id | event_id | quantity | dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 3 | timestamp |
| 2 | 1000 | -2 | timestamp |
| 3 | 2000 | 5 | timestamp |
| 4 | 1000 | 3 | timestamp |
| 5 | 2000 | 2 | timestamp |

However if each event has a new record added every 1 second, and I want to regularly query to get the latest balance, how would you keep this performant? Summing potentially 36,000 records per day for a period of several weeks surely isn't a good option.

I figure I could roll up the balances of each event_id on some schedule and delete those events based on date time. This poses a several issues in itself;

1. I lose the full history of events (I could keep all events in an additional table for this purpose)
2. I might introduce another set of performance issues with querying/delete records on an already busy table
3. I need some scheduled job to maintain records periodically, I assume I could use a stored procedure to choose certain event_id's to tidy up.

I know this is a highly abstract question, however I don't personally have the knowledge and experience with SQL to come up with a better design.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. Also: MySQL or Postgres. Please tag only one database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for an assignment operator query:
I used table name `item_data`

> SELECT *, @running_qty:=@running_qty+quantity AS runningQty  FROM
> (SELECT * FROM `item_data` i) a JOIN (SELECT @running_qty:=0)rn GROUP
> BY event_id

Comment: Is the use of an assignment operator useful in somehow making the summation faster over a large data set? How is it different from `SELECT SUM (quantity) AS quantity
FROM ledger
WHERE event_id = 1000;`

Comment: Your  question says "aggregated balances". I suppose you mean cumulative sum.
Hence, the assignment operator. 
`SELECT SUM (quantity) AS quantity FROM ledger WHERE event_id = 1000;`
This will only give you sum for event_id 100 and not aggregated function. What is your desired output, please post